# On android, how to get dimensions of ImageView?

Tags: android

I would like to find the dimensions of an ImageView to use to scale a Bitmap, prior to to calling view.setImageBitmap.  ImageView.getWidth and ImageView.getHeight return 0 if no image has been set.  (Presumably because the ImageView has not yet been measured?).  Is there anyway to determine the dimensions of the ImageView prior to setting the Bitmap?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's layout parameters (i.e. `layout_width` and `layout_height`) are set to `wrap_content` then the returned value is totally correct. You have to specify `minWidth` and `minHeight` in the XML or throught Java but then you know the minimum dimensions anyway.

Comment: but if I want an ImageView to take up the whole page, wouldn't I want to let android handle the laying out of the image, so I don't have to worry about variable screen resolutions and aspect ratios?

Comment: Would it be silly to do something like this?: on startup, instantiate a white bitmap based on the screen dimensions, and display the image in the ImageView.  This way, when I call for the dimensions of the view, it will be informative.  And the ImageView will have a white default image.  (Apparently ImageView.setBackground(color) is not useful for an empty ImageView).

Comment: Like what exactly is it you are trying to achieve?